# How to differentiate between image link and href link in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to get the name of the links of wikipedia home page in selenium webdriver . In the home page there is a table at the bottom which contains the link of wikipedia sister projects like Media-wiki, meta wiki etc . But after running the code I am getting  24 links. But in the webpage there are only 12 links. My suspicion is it is taking the links of images also.

package tcsWebmail;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class WikiPediaLinks {

public static void main(String[] args) {
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

WebElement Block=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='mp-sister']/table//a[not(img)]"));

List<WebElement> Links= Block.findElements((By.tagName("a")));
System.out.println("Printing the no of items in block");
int i=0;
for ( i=0;i<Links.size();i++){
System.out.println(Links.get(i).getText());
}
System.out.println("The no of items are"+Links.size());
driver.quit();
}
}
```

Comment: you forget your code :_D

Comment: @fabesky I just added. Was not able to add before for formatting issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XPath includes images as you suspect. In order to get `a` that don't contain a descendant `img`, you can to use XPath below:

```
//*[@id='mp-sister']/table//a[not(img)]
```

or

```
//*[@id='mp-sister']/table//a[not(descendant::*[local-name() = 'img'])]
```

See code below:

```
List<WebElement> Links= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='mp-sister']/table//a[not(img)]"));
```

Comment: Thanks @Buaban for the answer. But after using both the xpath you mentioned , the list is returning number of items as 0.

Comment: @amlandey could you update the question with your latest code? I'm sure my Xpath is correct so the problem might be in another line.

Comment: @amlandey i've added the code to my answer. You don't need to get Block, just get the Links in one shot.

Comment: @amlandey Sorry, I mean could you mark my post as the correct answer for your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
In for loop put another condition to check to validate imgage (img) or link (href)

List<WebElement> Links= Block.findElements((By.tagName("a")));
System.out.println("Printing the no of items in block");
for ( int i=0;i<Links.size();i++)
{
if(Links.get(i).getAttribute("href").contains("http://")
{System.out.println(Links.get(i).getText());
}
driver.quit();
}
}
```